# How do I extract the private key from a PKCS#12 container and save it in PKCS#8 format?

Tags: go, pkcs#12, pkcs#8

I want to be able to send iOS *APNS* push notifications using *AWS SNS* with the aws **golang** SDK. I've created a p12 file following this instructions: https://support-aws.s3.amazonaws.com/Exporting-APNS-Cert-Keychain-Mac.pdf
now in order to get the private key and cert I need to implement the following openssl equivalent commands:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in MyCertificates.p12 -out MyCer.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in MyCertificates.p12 -out MyKey.pem -nocerts -nodes
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in MyKey.pem -outform pem -nocrypt -out MyKeyCorrectFormat.pem
```

I can't find a way to do this in **golang**, any help will be appreciated. What seems to be the issue is converting the private key to pkcs8 format.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have been trying to do (in order to compile you need to change the first import in github.com/youmark/pkcs8 to golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2) :

```go
import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/youmark/pkcs8"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12"
)

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("myP12File.p12")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    password := "123456"
    _, pKey, err := Decode(b, password)
    pKeyPkcs8, err := pkcs8.ConvertPrivateKeyToPKCS8(pKey, passwordBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(pKeyPkcs8))
}

// Decode and verify an in memory .p12 certificate (DER binary format).
func Decode(p12 []byte, password string) (*x509.Certificate, *rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    // decode an x509.Certificate to verify
    privateKey, cert, err := pkcs12.Decode(p12, password)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    if err := verify(cert); err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    // assert that private key is RSA
    priv, ok := privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
    if !ok {
        return nil, nil, errors.New("expected RSA private key type")
    }
    return cert, priv, nil
}

// verify checks if a certificate has expired
func verify(cert *x509.Certificate) error {
    _, err := cert.Verify(x509.VerifyOptions{})
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch e := err.(type) {
    case x509.CertificateInvalidError:
        switch e.Reason {
        case x509.Expired:
            return ErrExpired
        default:
            return err
        }
    case x509.UnknownAuthorityError:
        // Apple cert isn't in the cert pool
        // ignoring this error
        return nil
    default:
        return err
    }
}

// Certificate errors
var (
    ErrExpired = errors.New("certificate has expired or is not yet valid")
)
```

What I get when printing the converted key is gibberish, so I guess there is something wrong with my decoding process somewhere.

Comment: Why would you want to do that every single time? Isn't it enough to convert the certificate once and always use the converted format from there?

Comment: Sure, I won't do the conversion each time. But do you know how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in go after you have already done it in the command line?

Comment: Sorry, I understand your comment now. I need to be able to do it programtically to many apps, through our golang web server

Comment: Since you're asking, it appears you googled for `golang+"pkcs#8"` and found [this package](https://godoc.org/github.com/youmark/pkcs8) then googled for `golang+"pkcs#12"` and found [this package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12), you then tried to make them work together and failed, right? Then what exactly did not work?

Comment: I've put my current code in the question, in EDIT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're there. You've converted the key to PKCS#8 format, but it's displaying as gibberish because it's printed in binary DER form. The key just needs to be encoded in pem format.

One way to test this is by creating your own pkcs#12 file containing a [self signed certificate & key](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go). A benefit is you can vary the expiry duration to exercise your certificate expiry error handling:

```
go run generate_cert.go -ca -duration 30m -host gooble.com
```

It generates key.pem and cert.pem. Combine key & cert:

```
cat key.pem cert.pem > both.pem
```

Bundle into pkcs#12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in both.pem -out bundle.12 -nodes -password pass:123456
```

Here bundle.12 is a pkcs#12 file in binary DER form containing a certificate and private key, protected by a password.

Run the go program (see source below) to extract the certificate and key:

```
go run pk.go -in bundle.12 -outkey key8.pem -outcert outcert.pem -password 123456
```

The extracted certificate is identical to the original certificate. The extracted private key is similar to the original private key, but now in pkcs#8 format.

You can extract the original rsa key from the pkcs8 file. The original key.pem is identical to key.final.pem:

```
openssl rsa -in key8.pem -out key.final.pem
```

You could also verify the extracted pkcs#8 private key has the same modulus as the original certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -modulus
Modulus=AEB5770C4DA8D...05E12398BE1

openssl rsa -in key8.pem -noout -modulus
Modulus=AEB5770C4DA8D...05E12398BE1
```

Note that the extracted pkcs#8 private key is unencrypted; that may not be what you want depending on how the key's going to be used.

Here's a slightly modified version of the go program (pk.go):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "flag"
    "github.com/youmark/pkcs8"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    in       = flag.String("in", "", "pkcs#12 input file (private key and certificate only)")
    password = flag.String("password", "", "to unlock the pkcs#12 bundle")
    outkey   = flag.String("outkey", "", "output filename of private key in pkcs#8 PEM format")
    outcert  = flag.String("outcert", "", "output filename of certificate in PEM format")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *in == "" || *password == "" || *outkey == "" || *outcert == "" {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*in)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKey, certificate, err := pkcs12.Decode(data, *password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := verify(certificate); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    keyBytes, err := pkcs8.ConvertPrivateKeyToPKCS8(privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //could write private key as binary DER encoded (instead of pem below)
    //_, err = ioutil.WriteFile(*outkey,keyBytes,0644)

    //write private key as pem
    keyFile, err := os.Create(*outkey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer keyFile.Close()
    err = pem.Encode(keyFile, &pem.Block{Type: "PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: keyBytes})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    certFile, err := os.Create(*outcert)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer certFile.Close()
    err = pem.Encode(certFile, &pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: certificate.Raw})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// verify checks if a certificate has expired
func verify(cert *x509.Certificate) error {
    _, err := cert.Verify(x509.VerifyOptions{})
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch e := err.(type) {
    case x509.CertificateInvalidError:
        switch e.Reason {
        case x509.Expired:
            return ErrExpired
        default:
            return err
        }
    case x509.UnknownAuthorityError:
        // Apple cert isn't in the cert pool
        // ignoring this error
        return nil
    default:
        return err
    }
}

// Certificate errors
var (
    ErrExpired = errors.New("certificate has expired or is not yet valid")
)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to do that the other way around? Here you split the pkcs12 container into the private and public key it contains. I would like to do it the other way around in go. Creating the pkcs12 container using the public and the private key. The equivalent `openssl` command looks like this: `openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey input.key -in input.crt -out output.p12 -name "foo"`. How to do that in go?

Comment: @xh3b4sd encoding isn't implemented in go as far as I know. Is PEM a possible alternative for you? _A simpler, alternative format to PKCS #12 is PEM which just lists the certificates and possibly private keys as Base 64 strings in a text file_ [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12).  Or possibly run the export in openssl as an external command?

Comment: I already have PEM encoded certificates. I want to use these to create pkcs12 containers which you can add to your browser. I also found out that write support for pkcs12 containers is not supported in go. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10621#issuecomment-251427487

Comment: Can you concatenate the PEM files and import that into your browser?